# I tried to input the pi symbol into my website but it does not show up

Tags: html

I was trying to input C=2πr into my website but the diamond with a ? in it shows up and not the pi symbol. The charset i am using is UTF-8

I tried to google it but found nothing

```
<button name="button" class="static" id="right12" style="visibility: 
visible;" onclick="whatPlayer()" type="button">C=2��r</button>
```

I want to be able to see the pi symbol but i cant.

The unicode for the pi symbol is U+03C0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see Pi symbol, you can use HTML entities. Like `&Pi;`. Visit http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/pi for more information.

Using HTML entities is much more preferable.

```html
<button name="button" class="static" id="right12" style="visibility: 
    visible;" onclick="whatPlayer()" type="button">C=2&pi;r</button>
```